# How to select a great grandchild of an element by its id

Tags: html, css

I'm supposed to be removing images of graffiti off of a wall. The exercise is supposed to help teach me how to use selectors in different ways. The tricky bit is that I am competing with a second style sheet and I am trying to make a new style sheet to remove the images of graffiti.

This is the relevant code I am working with:

```
<div id="wall">
  <div class="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div id="tag-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So what I need to do is select

```
<div id="tag-6"></div>
```

I understand that I am selecting a great grandchild of `<div id="wall">` I even understand that it is not the first child but everything I have tried so far does not work.

This is what my CSS looks like:

```css
#wall .parent > div > div {
    display: none;
}
```

I also looked up the solution to this problem and it looked like this:

```css
body div#wall div.parent div:last-child div#tag-6 {
    display: none; 
}
```

Yet when I copied and pasted this CSS code into my stylesheet, it did not work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your first selector works fine.  You're simply missing a closing quote on `"wall`.

Comment: Your selector should work although you should target it by ID. You are missing a closing `"` which makes it not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it has an ID, you don't need any combined selectors, just use `#tag-6` as a selector

```
#tag-6 { display: none; }
```

Addition after edit of question:

Just make sure your own stylesheet is referenced *after* the stylesheet whose styles you want to overrule.

Comment: Sorry @Johannes I failed to mention that I am competing with another style sheet and the purpose of this code challenge is to make a second style sheet with more authority. This is what I'm up against: `div#wall div.parent div:last-child div#tag-6`

Comment: @MauriceCunningham see the addition to my answer

Comment: Oh I see. I moved the order of the links to style sheets and it all worked out. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#wall .parent > div #tag-6 {
  display: none;
}
```

The most obvious method is the direct route:

```
#tag-6 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: What's crazy is that I have been trying the first suggestion you made and nothing happened, but when I moved the reference to this style sheet below the one I am trying to override it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo

```
<div id="wall>
```

should be

```
<div id="wall">
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I made in posting the question the HTML page correctly closes the quote.

Comment: @MauriceCunningham then you need to post more information because your selector works https://fiddle.jshell.net/uj79mhk7/